# How to produce nice qualitative bar composition graphs

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot

Here is my data:

```
ind <- c( rep(1, 20), rep (2, 20), rep (3, 20), rep(4, 20))
bar <- c(rep(rep(1:4, each = 5),  4))

mark <- c(rep ("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5),
          rep("B", 20), rep("C", 20), "A", "B", "C", "A", "C","A",
          "D", "D", "D", "D","A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B","B",
          "C","C","C")

dataf <- data.frame(ind, bar, mark)
```

Each individual (ind) has 4 bars in order and are color fomatted. There should be larger space between individuals. I might have any number of individuals. The following expected graph drawn in excel, I want to create more pretty graph in R instead.

[image]

Please note that each ind level (1:4) as four bar (1:4). All four bars for each ind are grouped in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the `rect` function to individually plot each rectangle. Try running a loop to iterate through each box in the stack:

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))

for(i in unique(ind)) {
  plot(0, col=0, bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab = i, ylab = "", xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(-6, -1))
  for(j in 1:4) {
    for(k in 1:5) {
      rect(j-0.4, -k-1, j+0.4, -k, col = which(unique(mark)==matrix(mark[ind==i], 5, 4)[k,j])+1, border = rgb(0,0,0,0))
      text(j, -k-0.5, labels = matrix(mark[ind==i], 5, 4)[k,j])
    }
    rect(j-0.4, -6, j+0.4, -1)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank for the correct answer. Can we put margin rectangle around each graph

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option using `ggplot`:

```
dataf$y <- rep(5:1,times = 16)

ggplot(dataf,aes(x=bar,y=y)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ind) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = mark),colour = "black") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = mark)) + 
    labs(x = NULL,y = NULL) +
    opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank(),axis.text.y = theme_blank())
```

[image]

Since I'm using `geom_tile`, you lose the separation between the 'bars'. The only other option would be to use `geom_rect`, I think, and specifying the coordinates for that will be more involved.

Comment: thank you for the answer ...but I would need space between bars (for symbolic purpose) and no lines within each bar...

Comment: @John Well, that's the price you pay for being picky! ;) If you already have the plot in Excel, just use that.

Comment: @hadley I don't see a width argument in the [docs](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_tile.html) and it doesn't seem to have an effect when I try it. Could you enlighten me?